# Python - Recursividad como protección contra pérdidas de conexión

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursión, python-requests

¿Cuál es la mejor estrategia para defenderse ante una conexión inestable que pueda provocar interrupciones en nuestro programa? Supongamos que tenemos que leer información de una página, pero por motivos de cobertura, de la propia página web, u otros, no podemos asegurar la ininterrumpibilidad del servicio. En estos casos, **¿procedería utilizar una función recursiva?** Por ejemplo, una versión recursiva de:

```
import requests, time

def conectar_al_servidor(enlace):
    modus = requests.get(enlace)
    assert modus.status_code == 200
    return modus

def main(enlace='https://www.enlace.com/', segundos=0.5, ciclos):
    mento = 0
    try:
        mento = conectar_al_servidor(enlace)
    except AssertionError:
        time.sleep(segundos)
        try:
            mento = conectar_al_servidor(enlace)
        except AssertionError:
            time.sleep(segundos)
            try:
                mento = conectar_al_servidor(enlace)
            except AssertionError:
        #y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a 'n' ciclos, y en ese momento:
                except AssertionError:
                    print("No se puede conectar con el servidor después de", ciclos,"intentos. Se finalizará el programa.")
                    quit()
    if mento != 0:
        #Se ha recuperado la conexión con el servidor, ahora vamos a procesar la información que hemos obtenido:
        return(procesar(mento, arg0=0, arg1=[1], arg2={2} ... argn='n'))
```

Si Vds conocen alguna otra manera más eficiente de detener el programa y reanudarlo una vez regrese la conexión, lo tendré en cuenta, por supuesto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que pones en la pregunta no es recursivo. La recursividad implica que una función se llame a sí misma (o llame a otra función que a su vez llama a la primera, etc.)

Cualquier solución recursiva a un problema cabe plantearla también como iterativa, es decir, mediante algún tipo de bucle.

Generalmente la versión iterativa suele ser más eficiente, y no incurre en el problema de que la recursividad puede agotar la pila (por ejemplo, en python, hay un máximo de 1000 llamadas anidadas de funciones. Si una función se llama a sí misma más de 1000 veces, sin retornar todavía en niguna de ellas, se agota la pila de recursión y el programa rompe). Un bucle no está sujeto a esta restricción, y puede ejecutarse muchas más veces.

El código que muestras, como dije, no es recursivo ya que la función `conectar_al_servidor()` no contiene llamadas a `conectar_al_servidor()`, ni a `main()`. Pero tampoco le hace falta para nada.

Entiendo que lo que quieres es hacer una función que detecte un mal funcionamiento en ese servidor y que repita la petición, un cierto número de veces indicado en la variable `ciclos`. Para eso no veo por qué tendrías que anidar como has hecho los bloques `try`/`except`. Basta un solo bloque dentro de un bucle con un contador que detecte cuántas veces has repetido el intento. Algo así:

```
def main(enlace='https://www.enlace.com/', segundos=0.5, ciclos):
    mento = 0
    intentos = 0
    while intentos < ciclos:
        try:
            mento = conectar_al_servidor(enlace)
        except:
            print("Reintentando en {} segundos".format(segundos))
            time.sleep(segundos)
            intentos+=1
        else:           # Si no hay excepción, salir del bucle
            break
    print("No se puede conectar con el servidor después de {} intentos".format(ciclos))
    print("Se finalizará el programa.")
    quit()
```

### Mejoras

El tiempo entre reintentos generalmente se va aumentando (es lo que se llama un *exponential backoff*), para evitar saturar al servidor. Por ejemplo, podría duplicarse entre reintentos:

```
def main(enlace='https://www.enlace.com/', segundos=0.5, ciclos):
    mento = 0
    intentos = 0
    while intentos < ciclos:
        try:
            mento = conectar_al_servidor(enlace)
        except:
            print("Reintentando en {} segundos".format(segundos))
            time.sleep(segundos)
            segundos = segundos * 2
            intentos += 1
        else:
             break
    print("No se puede conectar con el servidor después de {} intentos".format(ciclos))
    print("Se finalizará el programa.")
    quit()
```

Por otro lado, la excepción que generas no es la más indicada. Las aserciones no deben usarse para comprobar condiciones que podrían aparecer normalmente durante la ejecución de un programa (como por ejemplo esta, que un servidor devuelva un error). Deben reservarse únicamente para verificar condiciones que *han de ser ciertas siempre*, y si no lo fueran eso indicaría que el programa está mal hecho. Es decir, raras veces.

Te recomiendo elevar otro tipo de excepción, como por ejemplo `ValueError`, o crear tú una propia. El siguiente código muestra cómo crear una excepción llamada `ServerError` por ejemplo:

```
class ServerError(BaseException):
    pass

def conectar_al_servidor(enlace):
    modus = requests.get(enlace)
    if not modus.ok:
         raise ServerError("El servidor retorna {}".format(modus.status_code))
    return modus
```

Yo usaría también el parámetro `timeout=` de `requests.get()`, pues si el servidor no responde, tardará mucho (varios minutos) en detectarlo. Puedes darle un valor más bajo. Si el servidor no ha respondido dentro de ese tiempo, `requests.get()` generará la excepción `TimeOutError`. Desde `main()` podrías capturar ambas excepciones así:

```
try:
    mento = conectar_al_servidor(enlace)
except (TimeoutError, ServerError) as e:
    # Puedes hacer print(e) para ver la excepción concreta
    ...
else:
    break
```